# What does "toy-contour" mean?

Tags: complex-analysis, terminology

When I reading Complex Analysis written by Stein and Shakarchi. In Chapter 2, he had introduced a notion "toy contour "without explaining. what does this exactly mean?

Comment: There is an informal definition on page 40 and some example are given on page 42.

Answer (score 5):

Taken from page 40 of the book,

[image: Stein pg 40]

Although presented somewhat unrigorously, toy contours are essentially always clear in use.

---

(This was upvoted recently and I re-looked at it. I am editing now to include the text of the image above so as to make this question and answer understandable to screen readers and other software that doesn't handle images).

From page 40 of the book:

> The following definition is loosely stated, although its applications will be clear and unambiguous. We call a **toy contour** any closed curve where the notion of interior is obvious, and a construction similar to that in Theorem 2.1 is possible in a neighborhood of the curve and its interior. Its positive orientation is that for which the interior is to the left as we travel along the toy contour. This is consistent with the definition of the positive orientation of a circle. For example, circles, triangles, and rectangles are toy contours, since in each we can modify (and actually copy) the argument given previously.